# Change order of online sources

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

Assume we have several website entries and we would like to start citation in the text with `a`, followed by `b`, etc. Using standard biblatex notation as follows, it can occur that `b` comes before `a`:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
    \field{date}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventdate}
    \field{origdate}
    \literal{nodate}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{wikipedia-link:General,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! General Website},
        url     = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:ITA,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! Italian Language},
        url     = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:ESP,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! Spanish Language},
        url     = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:English,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! English Language},
        url     = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
    \textbf{\autocite{wikipedia-link:General}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:English}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:ESP}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:ITA}}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So in this example, it would make sense that the general website overview of Wikipedia is mentioned before the first paragraph. So it should be labelled as `a`. Instead, it is currently labelled as `b` when you compile the example. Is there any suitable method to have an order that makes sense? Sorting on `urldate` seems wrong, as this field is not made for the purpose. `author` is by intention the same for all entries. `Title` leads to the wrong order, as shown in this example. `url` is also not suited. So the only option that remains is manual sorting based on the bib file entries, which would be fine for me. How can it be achieved for `@online` only? Other types of entries should stick to the normal sorting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for providing a nice minimal example document!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to override the sorting mechanism by adding fields to your `.bib` file. The following sorting override fields are available:

- `presort`
- `sortkey`
- `sortname`
- `sorttitle`
- `sortyear`

The `presort` field is useful for grouping items, and is not relevant here. The `sortkey` field if present will override any other sorting done. The other overrides are more targeted and will override the relevant sorting method if used (author/editor/translator), title or year.

In your case, because you want to order items with the same author and year,  you can use a `sorttitle` field to your `.bib` file with the ordering you want the related entries to appear in.  In this example I've put the general page first, by using `sorttitle={1}` and the language pages alphabetically by language name, by assigning the `sortauthor` appropriately to force that order.

P.S. I don't think that `author={Everybody}` is really appropriate for a Wikipedia citation but this is irrelevant to the main point of the question. See [Citing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
    \field{date}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventdate}
    \field{origdate}
    \literal{nodate}
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @online{wikipedia-link:General,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! General Website},
        url     = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
        sorttitle = {1},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:ITA,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! Italian Language},
        url     = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
        sorttitle = {3},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:ESP,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! Spanish Language},
        url     = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
        sorttitle = {4},
    }
    @online{wikipedia-link:English,
        author  = {Everybody},
        title   = {Wikipedia! English Language},
        url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
        urldate = {2018-01-31},
        sorttitle = {2},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
    \textbf{\autocite{wikipedia-link:General}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:English}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:ESP}}
    \lipsum[1] \textbf{\textcite{wikipedia-link:ITA}}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of references]

Comment: `sortkey` might be a bit too much, since it basically overrides everything (the name and year will no longer play a role), since this is about sorting entries with the same `author` and `year`, maybe `sorttitle` is more appropriate.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, you're right. It works in this example, but will interfere with other things. I've changed it to that.

Answer (score 4):

You can force `biblatex` to only consider name, year and citation order for sorting by defining a new sorting themplate. In essence that means that in your citations the first mention of `<Name> <year>a` will always come before `<Name> <year>b` etc. Your readers may not be able to understand the order of the entries just by looking at the bibliography data (because it is context dependent), but that may not be much of an issue.

Note that I applied the sorting for all entry types, not just `@online`, since the general scheme is applicable to other types as well and makes no less sense there.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  sorting=nyorder,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyorder}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{wikipedia-link:General,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia! General Website},
  url     = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
@online{wikipedia-link:ITA,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia! Italian Language},
  url     = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
@online{wikipedia-link:ESP,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia! Spanish Language},
  url     = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
@online{wikipedia-link:English,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia! English Language},
  url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{wikipedia-link:General}

  ipsum \textcite{wikipedia-link:English}

  dolor \textcite{wikipedia-link:ESP}

  sit \textcite{wikipedia-link:ITA}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations are ordered a, b, c, d.]

Comment: If I understand this, it simply forces these entries to be ordered in the order they are cited in the text? This doesn't seem to achieve exactly what the OP is asking for though.

Comment: @AlanMunn It considers cite order *after* name and title. The bibliography will still be sorted primarily by name and year, the cite order only comes in if there is a draw. This means that in the *citations* "Smith 2000a" will always come before "Smith 2000b", which is what I understood the OP wants ('we would like to start citation in the text with a, followed by b, etc.')

Comment: Ok. I guess we interpreted the request differently. In your solution, if the General page is cited after the others, it will no longer be first in the bibliography as in mine. So our two solutions solve slightly different versions of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two very good solutions. I accepted @AlanMunn 's solution, because he was faster and because his solution is less invasive, despite I think @moewe 's solution could be used in the general sorting algorithm used by `authoryear`. You need to decide if you want the text to be clearer (starting with a instead of b etc.) or the order of the bibliography. For me, the text is more important.